# PBKDF2 Rounds Implementation Question?

Tags: pbkdf-2, sha-512

Currently I am working on a implementation of PBKDF2 for an embedded microcontroller.

My question is that my psuedo-random function is fixed (SHA-512 HMAC) how do perform 'rounds' of encryption?

I am using a vendor provided SHA-512 HMAC implementation has been verified to output correct results for single iteration vectors. The parameters the SHA-512HMAC function are (message, message length, key, key length) to do rounds do it just feed the output digest of the function into the key input to my function?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. I'm getting a hard time understanding your problem. Are you asking that how many iterations do you need or how to perform the iterations for PBKDF2-HMAC-HHA512?

Comment: If you are not sure, look up [the standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8018#section-5.2). You need to implement function F; the password is the key.